# Access MDB on Web not Inserting

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic, odbc

I have a simple ASP application that uses an Access MDB as a back end.  I've created a system ODBC on my ISP's server called ParProf007 and they've setup the appropriate rights to the folder with the file.

My problem is that I can query the database and create new tables on it as well.  However, inserts do not do anything, nor do they throw errors.

As a test, I tried a basic, direct command on the connection.  I copied the MDB down to my local system and verified that the new table had been created:

```
<%
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open("dsn=ParProf007")

conn.execute("create table test (testid char(10))")
%>
```

[image: Proof that the Table was created]

And when I built a report against the table, I got no records as expected.

Next I tried another direct query against the connection:

```
<%
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open("dsn=ParProf007")

conn.execute("insert into test (testid) values ('xpd99111')")
if err = 0 then
  response.write("Success")
else
  response.write("Failure")
end if
%>
```

And the ASP printed "Success"

But when I (again) downloaded the MDB to my local system, I tried to query the table and again got no records, although this single record should be there.

What am I missing?  Why would my Access MDB allow creation of a table but not insert?  Is there some latency in Access?  Do I need to commit my transactions?  If so, how?  This process works exactly as expected on my local web server.

**UPDATE**  I finally gave up on using Access and created a database using MySQL.  Intermedia allows two free databases up to 540MB so for my purposes this was sufficient.  I still have no idea why Access didn't behave the same on the remote server as it had locally.

Comment: Do you close your connection correctly? Maybe there is an implicit transaction that is not commited until the connection is closed?

Comment: You could also try to include your execution in an explicit transaction with conn.BeginTrans and conn.CommitTrans.

Comment: If you verify the transaction is actually completing, look into DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823202%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: What is the purpose of err = 0? Are you using `On Error Resume Next`? If so you should use `Err.Number <> 0`. If you are using `On Error Resume Next` have you tried disabling it and seeing what the actual error message is?

Comment: Farther down, the connection is closed with `conn.close`.  After I posted this last night, I modified the code to place the execute within a transaction, but it still did not work.  In the main body of the code is an `on error` `resume next` just before the flurry of `conn.execute` statements.